# How to change some character values to numeric ones in a dataframe + selecting values within a column using values form another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, character, subset

First of all I'm sorry that what I'm asking is trivial to you, I am new to coding and bad at it too.

I'm working with a dataframe obtained from an excel file, looks pretty basic. I uploaded the actual excel file here so maybe you can use it if you need to: https://easyupload.io/s6hs29

All I want to do is to calculate the mean of all the values in column "Distance.moved1" that are within the time values 0:30:00-0:30:30 and 0:37:00-0:37:30 in column "X.1".

The first problem I need to fix is the class of the columns of the dataframe.

First, I need to change the class from character to numeric if I want to calculate a mean. Problem is, column "Distance.moved.1" contains some characters in the first elements.

If I run:

```
as.numeric(DF$Distance.moved.1)
```

it prints me all the numbers and puts NA in place of all the characters. I would be fine with this, but if I then check the column class, it still is a character.

So I thought, maybe I can skip the first character values and only convert the actual numbers to numeric, so the elements from the 5th to the last one in the dataframe. Is this even possible?
I tried this:

```
as.numeric(DF$Distance.moved.1[5:1350])
```

it seemed to work, no errors and correct print. but once I run this:

```
class(DF$Distance.moved.1[5])
```

I still get "character". What am I doing wrong? I guess I could delete the first 5 characters from the column and retry but  there must be a better way.

For the second problem (which I can't test until I figure out how to get numeric values):
I want to calculate the mean of all the values in column "Distance.moved.1" that go from the time 0:30:00-0:30:30 to 0:37:00-0:37:30, found in column "X.1".

A way could be using the element numbers for the 2 rows, something like this:

```
Mean1 <-  mean(c(DF$Distance.moved.1[65:79]))
```

But what if I want to use the time frames I have? Can I keep column "X.1" as character and just run this successfully?

```
Mean1 <-  mean(c(DF$Distance.moved.1["0:30:00-0:30:30":"0:37:00-0:37:30"]))
```

Please help and thank you!

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: I added a link with the CSV file I am using, so you can use read.csv and you have the same exact dataframe as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data requires quite a comprehensive treatment: reading in the data and adjusting column names, creating proper dates, finally filtering and computing the mean. Below is a solution using the packages `tidyverse` (for general data wrangling) and `lubridate` (for dealing with dates).

I suggest you see the documentation to see what each function does. To do so, place your cursor within the function name and hit F1 in R Studio. I also suggest you read up on date-time objects [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html).

Probably you will have to tweak the code below because my column names differ from what you describe in your question and it is unclear what "start" refers to in the time field. But hopefully this can get you started:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# load data, rename columns
df <- read_csv("~/Downloads/NN trial 6-7-9-10.csv",
               skip = 5L,
               col_names = c("id", "time", "n", "average", "se"))

# create complete date-times, convert into interval objects
df <- df %>% 
  separate(time, into = c("start", "end"), sep = "-") %>% 
  mutate(across(c(start, end), ~str_c("2022-01-01T0", .x))) %>% 
  mutate(time = interval(start, end))

# filter and summarize (mean)
period1 <- interval("2022-01-01T00:30:00", "2022-01-01T00:30:30")
period2 <- interval("2022-01-01T00:37:00", "2022-01-01T00:37:30")

df %>% 
  filter(time %within% period1 | time %within% period2) %>% 
  summarize(across(c(n, average, se), mean))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>       n average    se
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  7.23    62.6  12.8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm going to try and follow advices, I never used those 2 packages but I know they are pretty popular and useful. What baffles me is having to use them for this, I thought dealing with a simple excel table for simple calculations would have been easier, would it be that hard to do everything using just base R?

Comment: You can certainly do the same with just "base R". The steps remain the same: make sure to skip the non-data rows when reading the data in, get the column types right, then filter and take the mean (or any other summary statistic). This is just what I am used to and what I find most transparent in terms of syntax.